# Laravel 5.3 Direct Home URI to Auth in Routes?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Laravel 5.3 newb here. I want going to `localhost:8000` to go to the login page generated by `php artisan make:auth`.

My routes `web.php` looks like this by default:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

This of course brings it to the default Laravel welcome page.

I change it to this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Which brings up the dashboard saying `You are logged in!` when no authentication has been done, so that isn't working.

I change it to this and nothing loads at all:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Have tried a few other things and nothing seems to work. Would also like the URI to just be `localhost:8000` and not `localhost:8000/login` or anything like that if possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 5 minutes after posting this, I realized I needed to do this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```